# Django: how to filter by day/month range without setting the year

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a course Model but want to add an available period date (optiona) on it, but without concidering the Year.

so I can:

- store 2 dates and wont concidering the years on the Course model
- or store 4 numbers (from_day, from_month, to_day, to_month) on the Course model

First I don't know what is the best solutions (what type of data to store, date or numbers?)
Second, I don't know how to filter later with checking the actual date.

If there is a date range in the courses, ex: 2022/12/20 to 2023/01/10, if we are the 2023/01/18, theses courses should be excluded

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()

def get_available_courses(self):
    courses = self.account.get_courses().filter(
        ...
    )
```

No need to set a year because it should concider any year

---

**EDIT:**

I tried a solution and I tought it worked but it doesn't :
I have 2 situation:

- When the date range isn't crossing the new year (that one is working "filter_not_year_crossed")
- When the date range is crossing the new year: "filter_year_crossed" (that one isn't done yet, I didn't found yet how)

  ```
    today = datetime.date.today()
    today_day = today.day
    today_month = today.month
    # we are by exemple the 15/02
    today_day = 15
    today_month = 2

    filter_not_year_crossed = (
    # CHECK END
    Q(available_end_at__month__lt=today_month) | 
    (Q(available_end_at__month=today_month) & 
    Q(available_end_at__day__gte=today_day)) 
    # CHECK START
      ) & (Q(available_start_at__month__lt=today_month) | 
   (Q(available_start_at__month=today_month) & 
   Q(available_start_at__day__lte=today_day)))

   filter_year_crossed = (               <=== HERE
   Q(available_end_at__month=today_month) & 
   Q(available_end_at__day__gte=today_day)
         ) 

  is_year_crossed = 
  (Q(available_end_at__month__lt=F('available_start_at__month')) | 
   Q(available_end_at__month=F('available_start_at__month'), 
  available_end_at__day__lt=F('available_start_at__day')))
    filter_end = Q(available_start_at__isnull=True, 
  available_end_at__isnull=True) | (
        (is_year_crossed & filter_year_crossed) | (~is_year_crossed 
  & filter_not_year_crossed)
    )

  courses = courses.filter(filter_end)
  ```

Comment: Do you mean you need to filter dates in example from 20.06 to 31.08? (Like in this example we would filter all dates in the summer time every year). If yes, then you'll probably need custom filter in custom manager https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers

Comment: Yes exactly. But it has to work if it's also like from 20.06 to 20.01(next year). But I think it will be a problem, no?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a datetime or date object, you can filter using the `__month` and `__day` options.

Like so:

```py
course1 = Course(
    name='Course 1',
    start_date='2022-09-01',
    end_date='2022-12-31'
)

course2 = Course(
    name='Course 2',
    start_date='2021-09-01',
    end_date='2021-12-31'
)


courses = Course.objects.all()

# below will return both course1 and course2, because the year is not checked.
courses.filter(
    start_date__day=1
    start_date__month=9,
    end_date__day=31,
    end_date__month=12
)
```

Another option, as you mentioned, would be to save the day and month in your database, without a year.

```py
course1 = Course(
    name='Course 1',
    start_day=1,
    start_month=9,
    end_day=31,
    end_month=12
)

course2 = Course(
    name='Course 2',
    start_day=1,
    start_month=9,
    end_day=31,
    end_month=12
)

today = datetime.date.today()

courses = Course.objects.all()

# below will return both course1 and course2
courses.filter(
    start_day=1,
    start_month=9,
    end_day=31,
    end_month=12
)
```

Comment: Sorry I guess I forgot to tell that I need to filter by a range. Like between from 20.06 to 30.12 BUT it has to work also if it's from 20.06 to 20.01(next year).

Comment: @Jer: the `start_date`, `end_date` or overlap with at least one day?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem with start_date, end_date or 4 numbers (from_day, from_month, to_day, to_month). I didn't find how to do it (how to filter correctly)

Comment: @Jer: no I get that, but if you thus have a timespan, your course also has a timespan. When do you consider it a "match"?

Comment: I guess that's my question. Actually I don't yet have any date or numbers in my Course model, that is the first part to do (related of how we do the 2nd part). So I don't know yet  how.
I will just set a date on each courses, meaning, this courses can be only available between these dates, but every years